# POST few parameters to DB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, angularjs

I need to write name and coordinates of the place to mongo.

Data comes from three input fields:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="address" placeholder="Search" ng-model="placeData.text">
<input type="text" class="coords" id="lng" ng-model="placeData.lng">
<input type="text" class="coords" id="lat" ng-model="placeData.lat">
```

And processed with Angular:

```
$scope.createPlace = function() {
    $http.post('/api/places', $scope.placeData)
        .success(function(data) {
            $scope.places = data;
            console.log(data);
        })
        .error(function(data) {
            console.log('Error: ' + data);
        });
};
```

Goes to Node.js:

```
// define model =================
var Place = mongoose.model('Place', {
    text : String,
    lat: Number,
    lng: Number
});

// routes ======================================================================

// api ---------------------------------------------------------------------

// create place and send back all places after creation
app.post('/api/places', function(req, res) {

    // create a place, information comes from AJAX request from Angular
    Place.create({
        text : req.body.text,
        lat: req.body.lat,
        lng: req.body.lng,
        done : false
    }, function(err, place) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);

        // get and return all the places after you create another
        Place.find(function(err, places) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err)
            res.json(places);
        });
    });

});
```

It works, but the problem is that mongo receives data only from first input ng-model="placeData.text". What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: How do you call your ```$scope.createPlace``` method?

Comment: <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" ng-click="createPlace()">Add</button>

Comment: Please `console.log(req.body)` at the first line of `app.post`

Comment: Could you add some logging to your Node.js app, to see what is actually recieved from client?

Comment: App listening on port 3000
GET /api/places 200 180ms - 800b
{ text: 'melburn' }
POST /api/places 200 349ms - 884b